# Angular application throws HTTP 0 in Firefox when page is quickly refreshed

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm working on an angular application and came across the bug that in Firefox, if we refresh quickly enough (often takes several times) the page will eventually fail to load and, in my case, displays an `HTTP 0` error code, which if I'm not mistaken means that an AJAX call was canceled before receiving the response from the server.

I have not seen this behavior in Chrome or IE, but I don't know if that's because the JS engines in those browsers are helping me out, or if it's a browser bug itself (in Chrome at least it appears that the refresh button for a page is disabled while requests are being made on page load).

Is there a Firefox bug, an angular bug, or a bug in my application?  If it's the later, how can I avoid this?